# Scrolling up UICollectionView don't move a UIView above it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I am working in a profile `ViewController`. This profile has a main image in a `UIView` `subclass` and a `CollectionView` gallery with some images. I would like to be able to scroll up the `UICollectionView` and move the `UIView` too, and if I scroll down, I want to watch again the `UIView` when the `collectionView` first item is showed again.

I have tried to do this adding the `collectionView` and the `UIView` to a `ScrollView`, but the `UIView` only scroll up if I touch it.

In this picture you can see my problem[image: Problem]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the view at the top a `Header View` of the collection view.

Essentially it needs to be an actual part of the collection view if you want this action. (That's the easiest way anyway).

So the collection view will take up the whole screen but it will have a header view. Then when you scroll the collection view the header will move out of view and then come back in when you scroll down again.